# What is the difference between a pandas Series and a single-column DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does pandas make a distinction between a `Series` and a single-column `DataFrame`?
In other words: what is the reason of existence of the `Series` class?

I'm mainly using time series with datetime index, maybe that helps to set the context.

Comment: Well they are different obviously, I think you are referring to certain operations that still return a dataframe either because you only have a single column dataframe or because the operation results in a single column dataframe. However when selecting a single column there is no ambiguity and this decomposes to a Series. You have to show sample code to explain what your issue is.

Comment: The main issue is that I don't see the need for a Series object, with different methods.

Comment: For one, there is a namespace difference.  Series have only a top level name, dataframes have a top level and a column name.  That can lead to significant differences in syntax for processing/creating a new series vs a new column.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question should still be answered. Even though one can think of `DataFrame` as a `dict` of `Series` (though that isn't the current implementation), it's still unclear why you would ever return a `Series` object instead of a `DataFrame` (ie conceptually a `dict` with one entry).

Comment: @Alex's comment from 2018 is still relevant, IMO.

Comment: @EdChum well that is not true. Consider dataframe.loc[:, string] vs dataframe.loc[:, [string]]: one column is selected in either case but returned type is, respectively, Series and DataFrame.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Quoting the [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

> `pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)`
>
> Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data structure with labeled axes (rows and columns). Arithmetic operations align on both row and column labels. **Can be thought of as a dict-like container for Series objects.** The primary pandas data structure.

So, the **Series is the data structure for a single column of a `DataFrame`**, not only conceptually, but literally, i.e. the data in a `DataFrame` is actually stored in memory as a collection of `Series`.

Analogously: *We need both lists and matrices, because matrices are built with lists. Single row matricies, while equivalent to lists in functionality still cannot exist without the list(s) they're composed of.*

They both have extremely similar APIs, but you'll find that `DataFrame` methods always cater to the possibility that you have more than one column. And, of course, you can always add another `Series` (or equivalent object) to a `DataFrame`, while adding a `Series` to another `Series` involves creating a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My question was inspired by a bug in my code when a selection on a dataframe suddenly returned a series instead and I could not access the columns attribute.  I'm not the only one confused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782323/python-pandas-keep-selected-column-as-dataframe-instead-of-series?lq=1

Comment: I see. Perhaps it would help if they had a different `__repr__` behavior, so you can't mix them up?

Comment: You cannot conclude anything about the actual internal data structure of a `DataFrame` from `Can be thought of as a dict-like container for Series objects`. In fact, it's currently stored as a `BlockManager` (which is an implementation detail you should not rely on).

Comment: I am still confused, so when would i use a Single Column dataframe instead of a Series?

Comment: `Series is the datastructure for a single column of a DataFrame`. So conceptually, a 10-column `DataFrame` can be thought as 10 `Series`, i.e. 10 pairs "index column + values column"?. Why this 10-times duplication of index column? I know they probably share the same memory bytes, thus no RAM is wasted, but still, isn't it strange conceptually @PythonNut?

Comment: I may be pedantic, but I don't see the OP's question of WHY series exist answered. I see an answer describing the relationship between series and dataframes, but not  an answer explaining why we should want to have a series as a separate data type as opposed to being a special case of a dataframe (namely one with only one column).

Comment: So, why would one ever use a Series over a Dataframe?

Comment: IMO, this argues that Series is a leaky abstraction, and argues that Series should not be exposed to the user.  Instead, one column DataFrames would be more useful.

Comment: I agree that pd.Series should not exist: there is no point in having it. Its existence at the user-level may lead to errors very difficult to detect. Compare the returned data type of dataframe.loc[:, col_name] and data_frame.loc[:, [col_name]] when col_name is a string: first is a Series, the second is a DataFrame. When col_name is a parameter received as input or the result of a computation it forces you to make zillions of tests.

Answer (score 16):

from the pandas doc http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html
Series is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding any data type.
To read data in form of panda Series:

```
import pandas as pd
ds = pd.Series(data, index=index)
```

DataFrame is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
```

In both of the above index is list

for example: I have a csv file with following data:

```
,country,popuplation,area,capital
BR,Brazil,10210,12015,Brasile
RU,Russia,1025,457,Moscow
IN,India,10458,457787,New Delhi
```

To read above data as series and data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
file_data = pd.read_csv("file_path", index_col=0)
d = pd.Series(file_data.country, index=['BR','RU','IN'] or index =  file_data.index)
```

output:

```
>>> d
BR           Brazil
RU           Russia
IN            India

df = pd.DataFrame(file_data.area, index=['BR','RU','IN'] or index = file_data.index )
```

output:

```
>>> df
      area
BR   12015
RU     457
IN  457787
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your code doesn't work. You may want to change `file_data` to `brics`, add a US line to the csv, and change `['BR'....'US']` to `brics.index`. Perhaps correct `pupuplation`.

Comment: @RolfBly: Thank you for pointing out those mistakes. It was silly on my part to make them. I have changed them. Thank you! And regarding reading that just an example I took hence random values.

Answer (score 3):

Series is a one-dimensional object that can hold any data type such as integers, floats and strings e.g

```
   import pandas as pd
   x = pd.Series([A,B,C]) 

0 A
1 B
2 C
```

The first column of Series is known as index i.e 0,1,2
the second column is your actual data  i.e A,B,C

DataFrames is two-dimensional object that can hold series, list, dictionary

```
df=pd.DataFrame(rd(5,4),['A','B','C','D','E'],['W','X','Y','Z'])
```

Comment: that does not answer the OPs' question

Answer (score 3):

Series is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding any data type (integers, strings, floating point numbers, Python objects, etc.). The axis labels are collectively referred to as the index. The basic method to create a Series is to call:

```
s = pd.Series(data, index=index)
```

DataFrame is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or a dict of Series objects.

```
 d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
 two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
 df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DataFrame` is often described as

> a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table

Because of this definition, we may look at the data as cells, like in an Excel spreadsheet, which has rows with a row number and and columns with a column header. Because of this simplistic view, the underlying data structure may be a bit surprising.

The `DataFrame` actually consists of `Index` objects for the axes labels (row and column labels) and `Series` objects for the column data.

The `Series` object provides encapsulation for each of the column data (which is held in a one dimensional `numpy.ndarray`), with row labels and the column label.

So a single column `DataFrame` will have one underlying `Series` object for the column data.

See [DataFrame data structure](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/pandas-dataframe/) for a simple example with a visual representation of the underlying data structure.

Answer (score -2):

Import cars data

```
import pandas as pd

cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', index_col = 0)
```

[Here is how the cars.csv file looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7WJ1.png)

Print out drives_right column as Series:

```
print(cars.loc[:,"drives_right"])

    US      True
    AUS    False
    JAP    False
    IN     False
    RU      True
    MOR     True
    EG      True
    Name: drives_right, dtype: bool
```

The single bracket version gives a Pandas Series, the double bracket version gives a Pandas DataFrame.

Print out drives_right column as DataFrame

```
print(cars.loc[:,["drives_right"]])

         drives_right
    US           True
    AUS         False
    JAP         False
    IN          False
    RU           True
    MOR          True
    EG           True
```

Adding a Series to another Series creates a DataFrame.