# Why do we need Python pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am learning Python. As far as I understand, Pandas includes Series and DataFrame data structures. It seems to me that Series is just a DataFrame with one column (along with the index column). Why then, do we need the Series data structure? Is the DataFrame not enough?

Comment: you can consider a DataFrame as a collection of Series ;-)

Comment: Certain operations were written to only work on Series objects. It's not safe to assume you don't have multiple dimensions when all you have is a Dataframe

Comment: `It seems to me that Series is just a DataFrame with one column`, no thats not true.

Comment: it's a developer choice.  Like matlab deals essentially with matrix, numpy use 0,1,2,N dims array. You find the same in pandas.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a pandas Series and a single-column DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks for the answers

Comment: Using a Series simplifies things when appropriate to use. When you use a Series, you know by heart that it only has an index and a data column. You don't need to worry about the number of columns, their respective data types, which column holds which data, etc. like in a DataFrame.