# Nested JSON into Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a Dataframe and one of the columns contains JSON objects of this type:

```
{'a': 'x', 'b':'y', 'c':'z'}
{'a': 'x1', 'b':'y2', 'c':'z3'}
...
```

How can I split such object and expand it into different a/b/c columns with their relative elements, within the same dataframe?

```
a     b     c
x     y     z
x1    y1    z1
...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your dataframe looks like this, with a column called `json_col`:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df
                            json_col
0     {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'}
1  {'a': 'x1', 'b': 'y2', 'c': 'z3'}
```

You can do this:

```
df[['a','b','c']] = df.json_col.apply(pd.Series)
```

resulting in this final `df`:

```
>>> df
                            json_col   a   b   c
0     {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'}   x   y   z
1  {'a': 'x1', 'b': 'y2', 'c': 'z3'}  x1  y2  z3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this method but I get the error: 'Series' object has no attribute. I have also tried the json_normalize method but same issue. Any ideas? thank you

Comment: You are trying to apply the method to a `Series`, so I assume your "dataframe" is not actually a "dataframe". I can't tell what format your data is in, but I would recommend you look for a method to turn it into an actual dataframe. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe) for reference

Comment: If it is really just a series analogous to a single column of a dataframe, `pd.DataFrame(my_json_series)` should work, replacing `my_json_series` with whatever your series name is.

Comment: Thanks so much I did that as it actually was a series and not a df. Only thing now is that when using json_col.apply, I get the ValueError "Columns must be same length as key"

Comment: You likely have more keys than the number of columns you are assigning. Here is a quick and dirty work-around: `df[list(df.json_col.apply(pd.Series).columns)] = df.json_col.apply(pd.Series)` (instead of `df[['a','b','c']] = ...`)

Comment: I get a df with 2 identical columns with the same items: {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'} ...

Comment: Sorry, it's really hard to debug without seeing your actual data... if you reformat your question with a complete example, I can give it another shot...