# panda DataFrame slicing has a KeyError: -1 Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have narrowed down the problem to the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'b' : 1, 'a' : 0, 'c' : 2}
c = {'one':[1,2,3], 'two':[4,5,6]}
p = pd.Series(d)
pc = pd.DataFrame(c)
print(p[-1]) # This line works
print(pc['two'][-1]) # This line does not work.
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "jdoodle.py", line 9, in 
>       print(pc['two'][-1])
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 766, in **getitem**
>       result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3103, in get_value
>       tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 114, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: -1
>   Command exited with non-zero status 1

`type(p)` is `pandas.core.series.Series`

`type(pc['two'])` is `pandas.core.series.Series`

My question is that `p[-1]` works but `pc['two'][-1]` show error KeyError:-1
I am really confused why `pc['two'][-1]` show errors. Need help. Thanks

Comment: @U9-Forward, I don't think that duplicate is most relevant for this problem. The issue is how Pandas treats `RangeIndex` and (as an extension) why chained indexing should not be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: It's even cooler than what I wrote before!**

I tested what you were doing and you can call `pc[1]` with no error but not `pc[-1]`. This is because `Series` mimics the normal list indexing behavior for positive integers ONLY!

So it's not that `pc["two"]` is `dict`-like, it's just how the `Series` object mimics `list` indexing. Even though my answer was wrong, I'll leave my old wrong answer for history.

---

**Old wrong answer**

The short answer is that you usually get that error when you try to access a `dict`-like object as though it were a `list`-like object.
`p[-1]` is accessing the last item in an ordered sequence like a list `[0, 0, 1, 2, "dog"]`

```
print(p[-1]) # dog
```

`pc["two"]` can't be accessed that way (because it is like a pure Python `dict` I think, from looking at your code.) `KeyError` is the same exception you would get if you ran the following code:

```
p = {"dog": [0, 2]}
p[-1]
```

In fact any key besides `dog` will throw the `KeyError` exception, I think. `dict`-like objects can't be accessed the way you access lists (i.e. integer indexes)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CharlesLandau, but here are some solutions you can solve it with:

First one, make it into a list before indexing:

```
print(pc['two'].tolist()[-1])
```

Second one, use `iloc`:

```
print(pc['two'].iloc[-1])
```

Comment: `iloc` is the most correct suggestion IMO and this should be marked as the answer @hui

Comment: What I really don't understand is why both of p and pc['two'] are pd.Series but one can get [-1] but the other cannot.

Comment: @hui Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe/26240208#26240208

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the other answers, the Pandas Series is immutable. Thus, it means the index values should be hashable. It uses RangeIndex indexing and thus, it only accepts positive integers. Refer to this documentation - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.Series.html

Answer (score 0):

Series with a `pd.RangeIndex` index do not support negative indices via `__getitem__`. Note `[]` is syntactic sugar for `__getitem__`. You can check the nature of the index directly:

```
pc.index  # RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
p.index   # Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Therefore, using a non range-based index works fine:

```
pc.index = ['x', 'y', 'z']
print(pc['two'][-1])  # 6
```

However, this an example of chained indexing which the docs [actively discourage](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) / [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) instead for integer based indexing. For example:

```
print(pc['two'].iat[-1])  # 6
```

Or via a single indexing operation:

```
print(pc.iat[-1, pc.columns.get_loc('two')])  # 6
```