# python pandas difference between df_train["x"] and df_train[["x"]]

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset and reading it from csv file.

```
x =[1,2,3,4,5]
```

with the pandas i can access the array

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
x = df_train["x"]
```

And

```
x = df_train[["x"]]
```

I could wonder since both producing the same result the former one could make sense but later one not. PLEASE, COULD YOU explain the difference and use?

Comment: The latter is a list, so you can create a slice of the dataframe with multiple columns from the elements in the list. I'd suggest you to read [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: you can put `x = df_train[["x","y"]]` but not in above one

Comment: `df_train["x"]` will fetch single column `'x'` while `df_train[["x"]]` this can slice the data frame to get data from multiple columns. As you are specifying one column to slice on in the latter you are getting same results for the two approaches

Comment: The first is a `Series` (possibly a `DataFrame` if multiple columns share the name: `'x'`), while the second is guaranteed to be a `DataFrame`. Many things will treat them similarly, but certain things require `DataFrames`, for instance `merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, you can slice your data frame in different ways. On a high level, you can choose to select a single column out of a data frame, or many columns.

When you select many columns, you have to slice using a `list`, and the return is a pandas `DataFrame`. For example

```
 df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]  # returns a data frame
```

When you select only one column, you can pass only the column name, and the return is just a pandas `Series`

```
df['col1'] # returns a series
```

When you do `df[['col1']]`, you return a `DataFrame` with only one column. In other words, it's like your telling pandas *"give me all the columns from the following list:"* and just give it a list with one column on it. It will filter your `df`, returning all columns in your list (in this case, a data frame with only 1 column)

If you want more details on the difference between a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and a one-column [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe) with very good answers