# Parse Data from column using if's

Tags: python, string, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe column that contains multiple different text qualifiers and I want to be able to set a new column that for each row checks if text is in each row and if so do this or this or that. I am trying to strip the data and just return the piece where it says vegetables and starch below, but due to a large variety of keywords in my data I can not just say if vegetables in COL1: col2 = vegetables.

Example:

```
     df['COL1']
0 PB~Cucumber_IT~_TL~Vegatables_SP~
1 PB~Potato_IT~_TB~Starch_SP~
2 PB~Onion_IT~_PE~Vegatables_BA~
```

I've tried:

```
for i in df['COL1']:
    if 'TL~' in df['COL1'][i]:
        df['COL2'][i] = df['COL1'][i].str.split('TL~').str[1].str.split('_SP~').str[0]
     elif 'TB~' in df['COL1'][i]:
         df['COL2'][i] = df['COL1'][i].str.split('TB~').str[1].str.split('_SP~').str[0]
     elif 'PE~' in df['COL1'][i]:
         df['COL2'][i] = df['COL1'][i].str.split('PE~').str[1].str.split('_BA~').str[0]
```

Expected output:

```
     df['COL2']
0 Vegatables
1 Starch
2 Vegatables
```

df.info() output:
* note - to fit I removed some columns and for privacy i renamed them. thiscolumn is the column in the df that I'm trying to use:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 54 entries, 0 to 53
Data columns (total 16 columns):
notthiscolumn4            54 non-null object
thiscolumn                54 non-null object
notthiscolumn3            54 non-null object
notthiscolumn2            54 non-null object
notthiscolumn             54 non-null object
dtypes: object(16)
```

I've gotten a variety of errors when trying different things such as:
- str has no attribute str
- i've tried using iterrows when it said that it was a np.object, but then there were index issues. 
- length of values does not match length of index.

Any direction is appreciated!

Comment: Hi JG518 welcome to SO, do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hello, thank you. I edited the above. Does this look like what you're asking for?

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output? Do you have only one col? in your code you are calling `COL1` and `COL2`

Comment: I've added in the expected output. I'm trying to create a new column with the new values based off of the original column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use numpy, pandas has a few different options for this sort of operation.

```py
import pandas as pd

def parse_row_col1(row):
    result = ""
    if 'TL~' in row.COL1:
        result = row.COL1.split('TL~')[1].split('_SP~')[0]
    elif 'TB~' in row.COL1:
        result = row.COL1.split('TB~')[1].split('_SP~')[0]
    elif 'PE~' in row.COL1:
        result = row.COL1.split('PE~')[1].split('_BA~')[0]
    return result


parse_res = pd.Series((parse_row_col1(curr) for curr in df.itertuples(index=False)))
```

This method, iterating over row tuples, isn't as fast as using numpy's `select`, but should be far less complex when dealing with a large number of conditions. Not only that, but as @rpanai points out in his answer, `select` can only handle mutually exclusive conditions, whereas the solution above functions regardless.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help on this. When I try to use this, I get the response Series object has no attribute itertuples. Do you know why this may be? I've updated the code to hopefully help further clarify my situation.

Comment: @JG518 The code above operates on a DataFrame, you must have given it a Series. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240208/11301900) for a simple explanation of the differences between the two. Solving this should be quite straightforward, just treat it like an error that occurred because you used a list function on a list item instead.

Comment: So a column of a dataframe is a series, correct? if so, do I just have to turn the series into a dataframe then run this? is there a way to do this on a series? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JG518 You could turn the Series into a DataFrame, yes, but what matters here is what you're trying to do, what makes sense. The code above is designed to work on the DataFrame that you showed in your post. Is that what you're running it on?

Comment: Yes, inside of a dataframe, I am trying to set each row of a column equal to part of the text in the same row in a different column. I.e col1 = col2.str.strip etc. but I'm running into null errors or attribute errors and more as I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Could you update your question, or comment here, with the exact code that is having difficulties with mine? My code takes a DataFrame, that's `df`, and returns a series, `parse_res`. All you would need to do is add that series to as a new column of `df`.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you are saying. I was missing that last step. Thank you so much for your patience, time, and help!!

Comment: @JG518 you’re welcome! I should have mentioned earlier that you can just add the new Series to your DataFrame, or even do everything in one step: `df[“new_col_name” = pd.Series(.....)” If my answer did solve your problem, don’t forget to accept it! Hopefully it will benefit others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC  this is a case where you can apply `np.select` see [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt ="""COL1
0 PB~Cucumber_IT~_TL~Vegatables_SP~
1 PB~Potato_IT~_TB~Starch_SP~
2 PB~Onion_IT~_PE~Vegatables_BA~"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt),
                 delim_whitespace=True)

condList = [df["COL1"].str.contains("TL~"),
            df["COL1"].str.contains("TB~"),
            df["COL1"].str.contains("PE~")]

choiceList = [df["COL1"].str.split('TL~').str[1].str[:-4],
              df["COL1"].str.split('TB~').str[1].str[:-4],
              df["COL1"].str.split('PE~').str[1].str[:-4]]

df["COL2"] = np.select(condList, choiceList)
```

You have to be sure that the conditions are all mutually exclusive.

Comment: I received an error that initial_value must be str or None, not Series.

Comment: Does your `df` has only a column and is it's type `str`? Do you mind to post the output of `df.info()`?

Comment: Please update your question as formatting in comment doesn't work.

Comment: added! let me know if that's what you were looking for.