# Difference between Series & Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

If we perform `value_counts` function on a column of a Data Frame, it gives us a Series which contains unique values' counts.

The `type` operation gives `pandas.core.series.Series` as a result. My question is that what is the basic difference between a **Series** & a **Data Frame**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of Series as a column in a DataFrame while the actual DataFrame is the table if you think of it in terms of sql