# I do not understand when to use a Pandas Series and when to use a Pandas Single Column Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I’ve done quite a lot of searching around and seen many posts that explain the differences but I have not come across clear use cases. I do understand the differences in general but I would like to know why I should learn how to use Series when it seems that a single column Dataframe might perform everything a Series can.

Essentially I cannot extrapolate my understanding of their differences into “when I should use Series or Dataframe for a task in front of me?”.

Comment: Also here is same/similar question on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe

Comment: In many cases, it won't matter which you choose. However, if you are starting with a single column and later in your analysis you plan to add additional columns, it's likely better to begin with a 1-column `DataFrame`. This will help you avoid issues where certain operations are treated differently for Series and DataFrames. For instance Series['x'] = 5 assigns a single row with the index 'x' the value of 5 (as Series are 1-D), while DataFrame['x'] = 5 assigns another column, labeled 'x', with values of 5 for all rows that exist in the DataFrame.

Comment: @Emrah Diril that SO question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe) was not answered. In fact there are 2 comments saying so. That question was one of the ones I looked at in my hunt for the answer to my question.

Comment: Hmm it has an answer now and it's pretty detailed, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240208/30581

Answer (score 5):

Here are my short explanations:

- `Series`: Series are for one-dimensional data, just like `list`s with a lot of functions.
- `DataFrame`: DataFrames are for multi-dimensional data, just like nested `list`s with a lot of functions.

Go to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) to learn more.

`Series` from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#series):

> [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas.Series) is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding any data type (integers, strings, floating point numbers, Python objects, etc.). The axis labels are collectively referred to as the **index**.

`DataFrame` from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#dataframe):

> **DataFrame** is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or a dict of Series objects. It is generally the most commonly used pandas object.

Comment: your answer does not answer my question in any way.I will ask the question again ** “when should I use Series or Dataframe for a task in front of me?”** So I need a clearly defined task AND then an explanation of why one is better suited than another...