# What happen when I use double bracket with DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, brackets

When I do this

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print(type(test))
print(test)
print('\n')
print(type(test[1]))
print(test[1])
print('\n')
print(type(test[[1]]))
print(test[[1]])
```

I get this.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6


<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    2
1    5
Name: 1, dtype: int64


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   1
0  2
1  5
```

I think it's natural I get series when I specify one of DataFrame column's key.

But I don't understand why I get DataFrame when I specify one of DataFrame column's key in double brackets.

What's haappening?

Comment: You are not specifying row key when you do `test[1]` but actually you are accessing dataframe's column 1. Check your column names, and they are `0, 1, 2`. Now when you try to access this `df[[1]]` you are passing a list of columns i.e. `[1]` and that's why it returns you a dataframe

Comment: Plz read this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe

Comment: thank you for your answer.now I understand whats happening.plz write it in answer, so I can upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying row key when you do `test[1]` but actually you are accessing dataframe's column `1`. Check your column names, and they are `0, 1, 2`. Now when you try to access this `df[[1]]` you are passing a list of columns i.e. `[1]` and that's why it returns you a dataframe.

Plz read this as well:
[What is the difference between a pandas Series and a single-column DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe)