# Pandas apply function is not resolving

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

[Please view the Data Frame by clicking this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTQQO.png)

```
Names=jobs[['Company Name']]
F = lambda x: x.split("\n")
Names.apply(F , axis=1)
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

When I run the following code, it works. Why am I facing this issue, I have never faced this kind of a problem before. PS: I got this data from scraping websites, unlike before. I am just hoping it has something to do with this

```
Names=jobs[['Company Name']]
F = lambda x: x.str.split("\n")
Names.apply(F , axis=1)
```

When I try it this why :

```
Ratings = jobs['Company Name'].apply(lambda x:x.split("\n")[1] , axis=1)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: no need for lambda when you're using the same operation on a single column use `str.split('\n',expand=True)` then join it back to your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the apply here, str.split is vectorized

```
jobs['Company Name'].str.split('\n')
```

should do the job.

I can not tell you why it had not worked before, but I can imagine it is due to the double brackets in `[['Company Name']]`. Single Brackets would collapse that to a Series while you keep the (2-dimensional Structure) of the Dataframe with the double brackets. See e.g. [Python pandas: Keep selected column as DataFrame instead of Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782323/python-pandas-keep-selected-column-as-dataframe-instead-of-series) for more details.