# Pandas Read csv just read a line of a row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a classic panda data frame made of ID and Text. I would like to get just one column and therefore i use the typical `df["columnname"]`. But at this point it becomes a Pandas Series. Is there a way to make a new dataframe with just that single column?
I'm asking this is because if I cast the Pandas series in a string (`columnname = columnname.astype ("string")`) and I save it in a text file, I see that it only saves the first sentence of each line and not the entire textual content, as I would like.

If there are any other solution, I'm open to learn :)

Comment: [have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782323/python-pandas-keep-selected-column-as-dataframe-instead-of-series)

Comment: This is a **classic** X-Y problem. You don't need to get a `pd.DataFrame` instead, show us how you are creating the text file.

Comment: But note, if you want the result of your operation to be a dataframe, jsut use `df[['column']]` instead of `df['column']`, but again, this is certainly not the cause of your issue

Comment: please do show some minimum amount of relevant code, you'll get more accurate answers that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: pd.DataFrame(dfname["columnname"])