# Pandas column name missing depending on adressing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df.speed # so nice cause of autocomplete...
df['speed']
df.loc[:,'speed']
```

are returning my data like omitting the selected column name

```
Time
2022-07-27 11:33:16.279157    45.000000
2022-07-27 11:33:16.628157    44.928571
2022-07-27 11:33:17.093157    44.857143
2022-07-27 11:33:17.449157    44.785714
```

Why is that missing??

I want it like

```
df.filter(regex="speed")
```

which returns

```
                            speed
Time    
2022-07-27 11:33:16.279157  45.000000
2022-07-27 11:33:16.628157  44.928571
2022-07-27 11:33:17.093157  44.857143
2022-07-27 11:33:17.449157  44.785714
2022-07-27 11:33:17.885157  44.714286
```

which means only this can nicely easily plot with correct naming of the value axis

```
df.filter(regex="speed").plot()
```

[image]

whereas

```
df.speed.plot(label="speed")
```

only works by using  `plt.legend()`

Is there a convenient way to do it?

Comment: How `df['speed']` could work and `df.filter(regex="speed")` returns a dataframe with a single column named 'Vehiclespeed' without a 'speed' column? `df` is the same dataframe for both case? How the legend could be 'speed' if `df.filter(regex="speed").plot()` returns a dataframe with the 'Vehiclespeed' column?

Comment: that is the most important implicit part of my question!

Comment: `df[['speed']].plot()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas: Keep selected column as DataFrame instead of Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782323/python-pandas-keep-selected-column-as-dataframe-instead-of-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `df['speed']` and `df.speed` return a Series.
- `df[['speed']]` returns a DataFrame, which is what you're expecting.

Comment: this explains the root cause!  Is it also possible to return a DataFrame by using the attribute access?

Comment: Eh, not really. You can do `df.speed.to_frame()`, but... why :')

Comment: Read through the link I posted under your question, that has all of the information~

Comment: why? attribute access provides autocomplete to create a new df to fiddle further in Jupyter.

Comment: can you add `to_frame()` to your answer then I will be happy to accept.
the linked Q does not really answer the essence of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add labels to each argument in your plot call corresponding to the series it is graphing, i.e. label = "Speed"

Then simply add Pyplot.legend() to the bottom of your script and the legend will display these labels.

```
df.speed.plot(label="speed")
plt.legend()
```

This should work, IMO

```
df.speed.plot(label="speed").legend()
```

Comment: `plt.legend()` did indeed the trick, but why is the column name omitted when printing only?

Comment: When you filter by column name, the `pd.Series` does not have a column/Series name for it, hence the legend name is not displayed on the graph. As mentioned abovem you can use df[['speed']] which gives you datframe instead of series